# How to change properties of sub-objects in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function that is called using the onChange property of an input field. The first console.log below reflects the changed value correctly. The second one does not.

I've tried deep copying newDisplayedAssignment and then changing the property. Didn't work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

--- New to React JS

```
function onDateChange(event, newDisplayedAssignment, key, assignment) {
    newDisplayedAssignment[key][assignment]['date'] = event.target.value;
    console.log(newDisplayedAssignment[key][assignment])
    console.log(newDisplayedAssignment[key])
    return newDisplayedAssignment;
}
```

Comment: This function looks like a handler which should update the state, but you don't update any state here. Did toy forgot?

Comment: My onChange looks like this... onChange((event) => {setState(onDateChange(...params))}

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't see changes because you have the same reference to the object.

Changing the reference should fix the issue

```
return { ...newDisplayedAssignment }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately that didn't work. The second console.log in the code doesn't even show the changed value so I think there's some weird dereferencing happening. I've tried destructuring each of the nested objects and no luck.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox? Seems like the issue is somewhere else

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-poitras-z9y1pp?file=/src/App.js      Don't judge the code too harshly lol

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to modify deep objects but it seems difficult and the code is inelegant,

There is a solution here (need to introduce a library)

I really want you to take 5 minutes to look at this library [immer](https://ttps://immerjs.github.io/immer/)

##### Example

```js
const deepObj = {
  first: {
    a: 'a',
    b: {
      bObj: {
        isAnimal: false,
        isBig: true
      }
    }
  }
}

// Now, let's try to modify the attribute of isAnimal
// Old way: is ugly
setOs({
  first: {
    ...deepObj.first,
    b: {
      ...deepObj.first.b,
      bObj: {
        ...deepObj.first.b.bObj,
        isAnimal: true
      },
    },
  },
})


// use Immer: It's great, isn't it ？ 
import produce from "immer"

setOs({
  ...produce(deepObj, draft => {
    draft.first.b.bObj.isAnimal = true
  })
})
```